# facebook like, tweet and google+1 buttons inside the loop on home, archive and search pages and missing facebook like buttons

Tags: loop, facebook, twitter, google-plus

Is there a way to add social media buttons, especially facebook like, tweet and google+1 inside the loop for each post on home, search and archive pages without getting masses of script downloads?

And on slight tangent, but not much, I seem to be missing facebook like buttons on half of the posts in the loop. Is there a limit to the amount facebook buttons per page?

You can check my code here - [www.pixelsandtea.com](http://www.pixelsandtea.com)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do this.  The first is to create a function that outputs the buttons and then include it in your template.  The second is to add a filter to either `the_content` or `the_excerpt` or both depending on where you want the buttons to show up.

In either case the first thing you need to do is separate out the script calls from the code that renders the buttons and add it to your footer either by hooking into `wp_footer` or manually placing the code in `footer.php`.

This example uses the Facebook html5 xfbml javascript sdk and the Google async method along with a Linkedin share button and Twitter tweet button.

#### Add the javascript to the footer

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_social_media_scripts' );
    function prefix_social_media_scripts() { 
            echo '<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';
            echo '<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
            echo '<script>
                    (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));

                    (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement(\'script\'); po.type = \'text/javascript\'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = \'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js\';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                    })();
                   </script>';        
    }
```

#### Function to render the buttons.

```
function prefix_social_media() {
        $post_url = get_permalink();
        $title = get_the_title ();
        echo '<ul id="share-buttons">';
        echo '<li class="facebook"><div class="fb-like" data-href="' . $post_url . '" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="66" data-show-faces="false"></div></li>';
        echo '<li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="' . $post_url . '" data-count="none">Tweet</a></li>';
        echo '<li class="google"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="'.$post_url.'"></div></li>';
        echo '<li class="linkedin"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="'. $post_url .'" data-counter="right"></script></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
```

#### Add filter to display before `the_excerpt`.

```
function prefix_social_media_filters( $content ) {
    $buttons = prefix_social_media();
    $content = $buttons . $content;
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'prefix_social_media_filters' );
```

#### Adding the function to your template.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

         prefix_social_media(); 

      // rest of your loop
```

Comment: Still getting a ton of script downloads and for some reason, I'm getting two share bars per post, still missing facebook button on half the posts. I've opted for your hook in method as I'd already tried the scripts in the footer way. At the moment I've only called the function on my search page.

Comment: I've fixed the problem of duplicate share bars per post, it was caused by calling the prefix_social_media(); in the loop, so I've removed everything regarding the share bar from the loop and relying completely on the functions.php file for this instead. However I'm still getting repeat script downloads and missing facebook like buttons.